# XCUITest how to output app.debugDescription in a tree format using NSLog

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, nslog, xcuitest

I'm running XCUITests on a cloud testing provider and the tests are failing due to locators not being found which work locally. Due to the nature of the app I am extremely limited in the locators I can use (no accessibility identifiers etc) so changing the locator isn't really an option.

The only way I can see the hierarchy is via the logs and I have attempted to determine what the hierarchy is at the point the test fails using NSLog and app.debugDescription. Whilst  this works, it does not output in the tree format so is virtually unreadable.

Does anyone have any ideas how to output the hierarchy in a tree format using NSLog or another means that would output to a log?